# Using an id to lin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have...

html:

```
<a href="#" class="link" id="1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="link" id="2">Link 2</a>

<div id="page1" class="page">1</div>
<div id="page2" class="page">2</div>
```

javascript (jquery):

```
$("a[class='link']").click(function() {
        var num = $("a[id]");
        $('#page' + num).fadeIn();
});
```

What I am trying to do is have a specific div fade in when a link is clicked. So if you click link 1 with an id of "1" I want the div with id #page1 to fadein.

Comment: Side note: IDs that start with or contain only a number are invalid in the HTML specification.  Compatibility isn't guaranteed, so you might want to change them to `link1`, `link2`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("a.link").click(function() {
        var num = $(this).attr("id");
        $('#page' + num).fadeIn();
});
```

FYI: HTML IDs that start with a number are technically not valid.

Comment: You could store the numbers as title attributes, and then use attr("title") instead of attr("id"). You could also use IDs like "link1", "link2" etc and then use JavaScript's split() method to get just the numerical portion of the ID.

Comment: thank you for your answer! (whoops... removed the previous question... i'm new, sorry)

Comment: No problem. Glad you're up-and-running. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a.link").bind('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#page' + id).fadeIn('fast'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close:

```
$("a[class='link']").click(function() {
    var num = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#page' + num).fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page).

What you're trying to do here is access the attribute of an element. You should do:

```
var num = $(this).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
$('a').click(
    function(){
        var divInd = ($(this).index() + 1);
        $('div').fadeOut(
            function(){
                $('#page' + divInd).fadeIn();
            });
        return false;
    });
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EHNDq/).

Note, also, that an `id`, under HTML 4, cannot *start* with a number. If it does, the html is invalid. Although html5 is more lenient and permissive, but remember to use the `<!DOCTYPE html>` (html5) doctype.